# Accessibility Service is not receiving onKeyEvent on physical devices, but is receiving fine on emulators

Tags: java, android, service, accessibility

I'm trying to create an Accessibility service where I'm trying to receive the key events.
This is my service.java:

```
public class testService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS |
                AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS |
                AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS |
                AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS;
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        // the service listens for releasing the key
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int unicodeChar = event.getUnicodeChar();
            if (unicodeChar > 0) {
                char asciiChar = (char) unicodeChar;
                // TODO:
            }

        }

        return super.onKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest:

```
<service
            android:name=".testService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:label="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>
```

I'm not sure whats causing the issue here? cause I tested it on emulators (multiple version of Android) and it works. But when i load it into real physical devices, it does not.

Anyone got any idea why?

It seems that in physical device, there are some programs that consumed the keyevents even before the event reach my service. but how can i check this?